# RVM acting up on terminal - Ruby 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, terminal

Can anyone explain what the issue could be with my RVM and my terminal?

I've `bundle install`ed a couple times, before realising that wasn't the case.
Also did a fresh install of Ruby and RVM. No luck.

```
davidfranciscus:~/hipcloset$ rails s
Could not find proper version of railties (4.1.5) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
davidfranciscus:~/hipcloset$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
davidfranciscus:~/hipcloset$ rvm use 2.1.2
Using /Users/davidfranciscus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
davidfranciscus:~/hipcloset$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
davidfranciscus:~/hipcloset$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

I've managed to implement a makeshift solution to solve the issue, but it's irritating not knowing why this is the case.

Comment: you should always be using `bundle exec rails s` instead of `rails s` so that all dependencies can be loaded.

Comment: i had similar issues when i used `sudo` with bundle by mistake

Comment: @karlingen that doesn't seem to be the issue here. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Nimir were you able to resolve those issues?

Comment: Could be that there was a selected gemset at the beginning, maybe selected using a dot-file. `ruby -v` won't tell you the gemset and `rvm use 2.1.2` without a gemset will select the root gemset for that version. `rvm list gemsets` will show you all gemsets and highlight yours with a hash-rocket. (The gemset is after the '@')